# How to find or compute or look for overall/max RPM by simply checking for rotation?

Tags: unity, physics, mathematics, rotation, axis

I find it hard to determine the wheel RPM since I'm only making a simple 2D game of rotating object via Z-axis. I wanna try [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/calculating-rpm.119999/) solution but I got no change since I'm trying to find the RPM from a game object that has a rigid body 2D and a circle collider. I decided to think of something more simple but alternate solution. I'm a bit good at math but not much. Took around to calculate but no luck yet. I want to know possibilities of checking its rotation from transform properties, figuring out yet about 6 degrees per second equivalent to 1 RPM as said from the link. I used the method `transform.Rotate()` for rotation speed. Also, when the rotation value reaches beyond 360, clockwise or counter-clockwise, sometimes it goes back either 0 or a negative value and I have to maintain total degree so that I can compute for the overall RPM. Please help me.

Re-direct from my original question: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1123755/how-to-find-or-compute-or-look-for-overallmax-rpm.html

Comment: what's wrong with using [Angular velocity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html)?

Comment: I'm not gonna use the RigidBody. I'm focusing the speed spin rate by obtaining the rotation from Transform properties only.

Comment: Also, I'm in a 2D environment. I'm using the 2D colliders and a RigidBody2D. However, I'm not gonna obtain degrees from RigidBody2D and instead I'm obtaining the rotation degree from Transform properties so that I can compute for the max or overall RPM.

Comment: RigidBody2D also has similar function, again similarly named [Angular velocity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-angularVelocity.html)

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna check it and test...

Comment: @Ali.S Nothing is working. Still 0 even my object spins at the fastest. I decided to look instead for the Transform.rotation and find a way how to get value beyond 360 degrees.

Comment: you never will... transform.rotation just states the current rotation of the object. it has nothing to do with the angular velocity (how fast it's spinning)

Comment: @Ali.S I see. I'm making an AA-based game. Google it to find out or YouTube. I'm making a big spinning dot non-stop. I'm using the Transform.rotate() to set speed. Regardless of the speed, this is where I have to look for the RPM base on how fast the spin is.

Comment: Rotate doesn't set speed, it merely changes current in the current frame... if you want to actually set speed, you've set angular velocity of 2drigidbody.

Comment: Then, why I still got 0? Does it have to be involved something like hitting each other collision to spin in order to work?

Comment: The Rigidbody only tracks physics speed. If you set a rotation using the Transform properties, the Rigidbody doesn't get an impulse (but it can muck with interpolation, so generally if you're using Rigidbodies you should drive all control through them, don't muck with the Transform directly). If you're rotating your object directly with Transform.Rotate though, you don't need to *infer* the RPM from the resulting rotation, because you're the one driving the motion - you can just take the rotational increment you're applying and adjust for the time delta.